# SDL ttf with opengl, font size issues

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-ttf

I am working with sdl ttf for rendering text to opengl, actually everything it's fine, but like you know, when you open a ttf sdl file you specify it on pixels, and you can't change the font size. Actually you can change the font size but you need to close and re-open the font, and that will be a little slow, so, is there any way to change the font size or something like that?

I need to do the following: Font size that can get resized and adjusted to the window screen (like the opengl -1.0f - 1.0f range that works with something similar to percent), multiline rendering support with no background.

Comment: *that will be a little slow* have you measured?

Comment: Hmm, do you recommend me to be opening/closing the font each time I render and swap the pixel buffers? That affects the opengl rendering speed? Please tell me :) Thanks

Comment: I've just asked you if you actually measured the impact on performacnce.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't actually... I'm not doing that because 1 friend told me that it was a bad idea and slow... Because im opening the ttf font from resource (.rc)... I will test it and I'll tell you.

Comment: It causes me a flickering... already measured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put it on a surface and scale the surface. That will probably deform the text, which might be an issue.

Or you could have an array of text sizes. Load the same font with a range of text sizes. As you scale your image, use the different fonts instead of changing the size of one font.

Comment: I have been thinking on that, actually, i'm going to do that! Great idea, I was only waiting for any confirmation.
I don't like to work with sdl ttf... but well, it's the closest library that I have.

Comment: The way my project is setup, I was unable to make FreeType work (I couldn't get past a black rectangle). If I tried running my shaders, nothing would render. I finally managed to get SDL_TTF to display text, although I have a bit of an annoying flicker because it makes use of an SDL_Renderer.